# Can I safely ignore MySQL error HY000 with error code 00000

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've set up PHP (5.2) with PDO (MySQL 5.1) to throw exceptions when an error occurs:

```
$pdo = new PDO(...);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Now, I get sometimes an exception that only tells me "HY000: General error". I've tried to get more info out of PDO, but all I can say is that:

- errorInfo(): `array(0 => 'HY000')`
- errorCode(): `array(0 => '00000')`

The query that fails looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO user_values
SELECT user_id,
       attribute_id,
       ?,
       value 
  FROM user_values 
 WHERE user_id = ? 
   AND set_id = ?
```

I've ensured that all cursors are properly closed (`$stmt->closeCursor()`). The exception is thrown when calling `fetchAll()` on my statement. After some searching around I found that some are just ignoring this error, but it seems just plain wrong to dismiss a PDO exception.

What to do? Do I have to check like "It's an INSERT, there is no result set so ignore those exception" (as I don't have separate methods for INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, ...).

Comment: Unless the rules differ because its part of an insert, you cannot use place holders for columns/table names...

Comment: The ? within the SELECT is used to insert a scalar value (in this case, an ID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

error code 00000 means successful (or rather no error found).