# PHP PDO UPDATE not updating data

Tags: php, pdo

I am having a tough time updating data using `PDO`.  These are the two options that i've tried.  None has actually updated the database, however.

Query 1:

```
$dateLastLoggedIn = date("Y-m-d  H:i:s");
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['User']);
$sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE users SET dateLastLoggedIn = ? WHERE username = ?");
$sth->execute(array($dateLastLoggedIn,$username));
```

`print_r($sth->queryString);` just prints out `UPDATE users SET dateLastLoggedIn = ? WHERE username = ?`

Query 2:

```
$dateLastLoggedIn = date("Y-m-d  H:i:s");
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['User']);
$sql = "UPDATE users SET dateLastLoggedIn = '".$dateLastLoggedIn."' WHERE username = '".$username."'";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
```

`print_r($sth->queryString);` prints out `UPDATE users SET dateLastLoggedIn = '2012-08-03 13:36:32' WHERE username = 'testuser'`

The second option generates the correct query but it doesn't actually update the data.  I can manually run the generated script and it works, but not through the `execute()`.  Anything i'm doing wrong?  I'm still new to `PDO`, so it may be a simple fix.

**SOLVED: see my last comment under the accepted answer.**

Comment: Do you actually have a valid DB connection?  What sort of errors do you get when you try to execute?

Comment: If you're using PDO, `mysql_real_escape_string` isn't going to work. At all. It requires an existing connection via `mysql_connect`.

Comment: Yea, my connection is valid...i'm using the same connection to do some selects on the page as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getting connection :
     function getConnection(){
        $dbhost="127.0.0.1";
    $dbuser="application";
    $dbpass="password";
    $dbname="abc";
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }

```
try {
  $dbh = getConnection();

  $sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE users SET dateLastLoggedIn = :dateLastLoggedIn  WHERE username = :username ");
  $sth->bindParam('dateLastLoggedIn',$dateLastLoggedIn);
  $sth->bindParam('username',$username );
  $sth->execute();
  $dbh = null; // after done
} catch(PDOException $e) {// simple exception handling
        error_log($e->getMessage(), 3, '/var/tmp/php.log');
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
}
```

Also, try to wrap this in try catch to see the error

Comment: That still doesn't update the data.  I am using $dbh elsewhere in the code to do a couple selects.  Do i need to close that connection and open a new one or something?

Comment: @ryanpitts1 ofcourse the getting connection can be a function by itself

Comment: Also with your code i get this: `Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )` when i use `print_r($sth->errorInfo);`

Comment: error code 00000 indicates success.. REFER: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044095/can-i-safely-ignore-mysql-error-hy000-with-error-code-00000

Comment: ok, so even if i hard code everything and just use `$sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE users SET dateLastLoggedIn = '2012-08-03 13:12:10'  WHERE username = 'testuser'"); $sth->execute();`  I get no updates in the data.  Is there something else besides this update code that i'm missing?  The connection `$dbh` should be fine, so i'm not sure

Comment: can you post what error_log message you were getting. As per my code: error_log($e->getMessage(), 3, '/var/tmp/php.log'); should be in /var/tmp/php.log. Or do you see any message echoed from this statement: echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';

Comment: Can you add this one after execute() and see: $sth->closeCursor(); REF: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php

Comment: WOW...well, i feel like a NOOB now!  Simple mistake, had the wrong database selected in my connection string - booo!  Thanks for the help though and sorry for wasting your time...did learn some new stuff though, so thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

> print_r($sth->queryString); just prints out UPDATE users SET dateLastLoggedIn = ? WHERE username = ?

That's what will happen with PDO prepared queries.

If you're using PDO, `mysql_real_escape_string` isn't going to work. At all. It requires an existing connection via `mysql_connect`. Your username value is effectively blank.

Comment: Ok, is it still safe to just use $_POST['User'];?  And if so would this work?

`$sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE users SET dateLastLoggedIn = ? WHERE username = ?");
$sth->execute(array($dateLastLoggedIn,$_POST['User']));`